# dd to copy only one partition of the iso to unallocated portion of hdd

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, dd

My question is more generic in the context of dd/harddisk/iso-images. Below are the details.

I have a live iso image which contains two partitions mounted as `/dev/loop1p1` and `/dev/loop1p2`, and I have a hdd with lots of unallocated empty space at the end. In addition, I have a usb drive connected (with same image written to) and the contents are available at `/dev/sdb1`, and `/dev/sdb2`.

So my task is very basic:

> Clone `/dev/sdb2` partition of usb (or the mounted iso `/dev/loop1p2`) to the empty/unallocated space in HDD.

I believe `dd` is the way forward as it is always the case.

**`if=` side:**

Eventhough `dd` accepts the whole disk (`/dev/sdb`) or the partitions (`/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2` etc) as the first argument `if=`, the remaining argument `of=` from HDD (`/dev/sda`) needs to be homogeneous & appears to be the deciding side.

**`of=` side:**

I have no partition created yet on the hdd side to pass it to the `of=` argument of `dd` command. If I use the full HDD `/dev/sda` as the `of` descriptor, existing partitions on the hdd will be lost, which is definitely not desirable.

So to reiterate the question:

> how do I clone the specific usb drive to hdd?

Aside, will it be of any help if I create somehow a new, empty partition on the hdd with "exact" dimensions to that of `/dev/sdb2` or `/dev/loop1p2` and use that as the `of=` argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will it be of any help if I create somehow a new, empty partition on the hdd with "exact" dimensions to that of `/dev/sdb2` or `/dev/loop1p2` and use that as the `of=` argument?

**Yes**, and this is probably the easiest way. The size doesn't have to be exactly equal, it may be bigger. Strictly speaking it has to be at least as big as the filesystem inside `/dev/loop1p2`, which *may* be way smaller than `/dev/loop1p2` itself. A way to obtain the exact size of a given filesystem depends on the filesystem (different tools for ext, btrfs, etc.). Having a filesystem way smaller than its partition is uncommon though, so the size of `/dev/loop1p2` is a reasonable and *safe* minimum.

If the new partition is too small for the filesystem, you will end up with unhealthy filesystem clone, possibly with some data and/or metadata missing. A proper `fsck` tool may or may not make the clone formally healthy but it won't recover any data that didn't fit in. Data loss may occur regardless of how much free space the source filesystem has.

If the new partition is bigger than nothing bad will happen. Whatever filesystem there is in `/dev/loop1p2`, it shouldn't care if the target partition is bigger. Creating a much bigger partition will be a waste of space though, unless you plan to enlarge the filesystem to take the whole partition afterwards.

So yes, the size of `/dev/loop1p2` is most probably the best for the new partition. Some tools may pay attention to partition types, therefore you should properly set the ID of the new partition (it's different for [DOS partition table in MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs) and [GUID partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)).

Can you clone without creating a new partition? Yes, but it's not worth it.

A device node like `/dev/sdx3` is just a useful abstraction to access a predefined fragment of `/dev/sdx` (and nothing outside this fragment). This means that instead of `dd of=/dev/sdx3` you can run `dd of=/dev/sdx` with *proper* offset (`obs=`, `seek=`), in general taking care you don't write beyond the fragment (`count=`). Cumbersome, but it's totally possible to clone your `/dev/sdb2` to the unallocated space on your target HDD without creating a partition there. But:

- any typo or calculation error may result in overwriting a part of the target HDD you don't want to touch (and then you will know `dd` stands for "data destroyer");
- although few tools can work with `/dev/sdx` and offset, you do need a partition like `/dev/sdx3` to *conveniently* use the cloned filesystem in practice, so sooner or later you will create it anyway;
- with no partition the space taken by the clone is considered free; no sane tool should use it on its own initiative but *you* can forget the exact size of the occupied fragment or even the fact it's occupied at all.

For these reasons creating a partition before cloning is the right thing to do. Once you have it, `of=` is the right way to point `dd` to it.

Comment: Thanks a ton!, One q: Is it possible to exactly match the partitions after cloning? After all, we are "cloning"!! I mean, including in terms of size.

Comment: @LovesProbability Usually. The unit is one sector, which may be 512 B or 4 KiB, depending on the target device. If 4 KiB then you cannot get every size possible with 512 B. Tools may also care about proper aligning, therefore they may insist on a size slightly different than you want. But the source partition is probably aligned in similar way. Even if not, it's not an issue because it's the *filesystem* that is cloned, few free sectors after won't matter. So if the tool advises you a slightly bigger partition, just accept it. Make sure the new partition isn't smaller, that's all.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of using `dd` to create restorable backups? If I create a partition on my target disk larger than my source disk, will I be able to restore it later to my source disk?

Comment: For example `sudo dd if=/dev/disk3s2 of=/dev/disk4s1 bs=16m` reports
`744546304 bytes transferred in …` and now restoring back with
`sudo dd if=/dev/disk4s1 of=/dev/disk3s2 bs=16m` reports
`744550400 bytes transferred in …`
Why are the numbers different?

Comment: @Shayan I cannot tell without additional data. Comments are not for solving extra issues (especially issues coming from a third party). Consider [asking a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).